# How to make a component listen and wait for data from another component without an event in Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular, components, angular-material, angular5

I have a problem working with two components (pop ups) in which i have to send data from a chlid component to another one (parent) who doesn't have an event to extract this data.
logically i have to find a sort of function that makes the parent listen to the changes made in the child.
The Changes have to appear in the same time in both components.
Could any one help ?

Comment: What do you mean without an event? That's exactly the right way to do it

Comment: try using a shared service and subscribe to the data from the component

Comment: i meant that the changes made in the child has to be shown in the parent in the same time without a click event that tells the parent to receive data

Comment: @CruelEngine i did that and the problem still occurs because i don't have an event to get those data from the shared service

Comment: @petrucci you need a setter and inside the setter call the ``.next()`` of ``Subject``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved: I used the @Host() tag to get the current instance of the Parent component and access the methode that changes it's attributes.

Here is what you should do.

First:
You should declate your parent component in the child

```
parent:ParentComponent;
```

Second :
you should pass your current parent instance to your new declaration in the constructor

```
constructor(@Host() currentParent:ParentComponent){
this.parent=currentParent
 }
```

Third:
Now try just to access the methods and attributes in the parent components

```
changeParentAttribute(){
    this.parent.iAmInTheParent();
    }
```

I hope you find this helpful

Comment: No, no, no, no, and no. In this way you are tying your child to the parent, effectively restricting them to work only one inside the other. It is wrong in so many ways I cannot list them all. Read the page I linked and start using the proper structure: Input properties from Parent-Child communication and Output properties (EventEmitters) for Child-Parent communication. Trust me, you will thank me later.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in your question. You need an Output property, which is the Angular generalization of a JS event.

In your child component:

```
class ChildComponent {
  @Input() someProperty: string;
  @Output() dataChanged = new EventEmitter<string>();

  whenSomethingHappensInChild() {
    this.dataChanged.emit('something');
  }
}
```

In your parent template:

```
...
<app-child [someProperty]="'someValue'" (dataChanged)="doSomething($event)"></app-child>
...
```

And in you Parent code:

```
class ParentComponent {
  ...
  doSomething(theValue: string) {
    // TA-DAA! you have the value.
  }
  ...
}
```

Please, do yourself a favor and READ THE DOCS, or, better, a book ;)

In particular:
https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components has a full overview of the basics of binding, which this problem falls into.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a shared BehaviorSubject to push values and both components have to subscribe to get this changes

Comment: i did that and the problem still occurs because i don't have an event that gets those data from the shared service

Comment: you don't need that event, when you get subscribed to a behaviorSubject you get the last value emited, this value can be the initial state or the last pushed state, is perfect for you, as far as I know.